# Arrow not showing properly in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to achieve the arrow pointing downwards...
right now its showing as trapezium there is some problem in CSS arrow code...
providing my code below.....

Output

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RRFR1WHZDYTF6LTQ/edit

```
<div class="icon__controls__controls">
    <div><a href="#" id="picture-zoom"><i class="zoom-out"></i></a>
 <a href="#" id="picture-threesixty"><i class="icon-threesixty"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.icon__controls__controls {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 2.1276595745%;
    width: 36.170212766%;
    margin-left: 38.2978723404%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon__controls__controls:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.icon__controls__controls [class^=icon-] {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    *vertical-align: auto;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.icon__controls__controls .zoom-out {
    color: red;
}

.icon__controls__controls:after {
    display: none;
    content: '';
    z-index: 3;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
            /* border-left: 5px solid transparent;
                    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

                    border-bottom: 5px solid black; */
}

.icon__controls__controls:after {
    border-top-color: #ef6f00;
}

.icon__controls__controls.active:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I used your code in **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogjp0oa/)** and there was no output... may be you havent provided the whole code associated with your elements.

Comment: what is .icon__controls__controls???? and @ImranBughio is right. No output. Create a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should simply follow this **[link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)** to see how CSS based arrows are made.

Comment: You can simply use,Unicode arrow pointing down,▼ - U+25BC BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE

Comment: Check This Out,http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/

Answer (score 3):

## [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/tLtnfcdt/)

[image]
This as basically all what you need to understand how it works:

STYLE:

```
.arrow{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.arrow:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:0px solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class=arrow><div>
```

if you want it to point up just switch `top`and `bottom`

```
    border-top:0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid orange;
```

Same for `left`and `right`.

I hope this will help you understanding how arrow are created.

Comment: thanks for your reply...did i miss anything in my code

Comment: Your code is working fine when i remove `display:none;` from `.icon__controls__controls:after` here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/1dk5ncgr/

Answer (score 1):

Basic sample :

```
<div class="arrowBorder"></div>

.arrowBorder {
  height : 0px;
  width : 0px;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/qusecu/4/watch?html,css,output

see more - CSS clipping or masking

Answer (score 0):

You should find the below bit more simpler

css

```
.arrow{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:relative;
      border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid orange;
}
```

html

```
<div class=arrow><div>
```